# ls on home directory very slow

Tags: command-line, performance, ls

A while ago, I accidentally created hundreds of thousands of files in my home directory which I subsequently deleted.

Since then however, running ls in my home directory has been extremely slow (taking tens of seconds to print). It has also been slow in other directories (as in taking 1s to print) and tab completion has been slow everywhere (also tens of seconds).

What might the problem be?

Edit: As suggested in the comments, the output of the

> find ~/ -maxdepth 1 | wc

is 67 and the output of df -h is

```
/dev/sda2        74G  8.4G   62G  12% / 
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup 
udev            3.9G   12K  3.9G   1% /dev 
tmpfs           795M  1.1M  794M   1% /run 
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock 
none            3.9G  4.9M  3.9G   1% /run/shm 
none            100M   52K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       825G  408G  376G  53% /home
AFS             8.6G     0  8.6G   0% /afs
/dev/sdb2       1.9T  584G  1.3T  32% /media/sj1/ResearchData1 
/dev/sdc1       932G  409G  524G  44% /media/sj1/ResearchData2
```

Comment: Hm.  Try running `du -hd 1 .` (`du` measures Disk Usage), and see if any unreasonably large numbers pop up.

Comment: I am going to assume that you emptied the trash, right?

Comment: Where is the trash folder? I didn't find it in .local/share where I thought it would be. At any rate, I rm -rfed those files -- actually I had to rm -rf my entire home folder because listing the files was taking too long. Maybe that nuked something important?

Comment: I'm trying to run du but it gets stuck. It computes the size of .gnome2-private. The next alphabetical folder is .gnupg but it gets stuck before it can print its size. If I try to run du on .gnupg, that runs fine.

Comment: du finished. I've a few very large folders with lots of files but nothing sticks out in particular. The home directory itself doesn't have very man files.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `find ~/ -maxdepth 1 | wc`. I am guessing you have very many hidden files. Also show us the output of `df -h` to see that you have space in the `/tmp` directory which might also be relevant.

Comment: Done. the # of files is only 67

Comment: Could you run a short SMART test on the disk just to be sure it has no issues?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and the reason was a link to a network drive folder which was not working anymore.

To see if this is the case for you, get a list of the links with:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type l -ls
```

Try `ls` with each one, the one that's broken will also lock up `ls`, so hit Ctrl-C to abort it.

After removing it with `rm` everything starts loading instantly.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Could you explain how you removed it?

Comment: I also had this issue. The tell-tale sign was that the delay was always 10 seconds, which is the amount of time after which autofs gives up trying to mount. I had a symlink in my home dir pointing to /smb/10.0.0.10/media which I removed using rm.

Answer (score 5):

Try `ls -1 -f /directory`  if we have huge number of files in directory.

- `-1` lists filename one per line.
- `-f` disables sorting.

Answer (score 2):

creating the hundreds of thousands of files might have created a lot of filesystem extents that do not necessarily get removed when the files are removed.  Get a "fragmentation score" with:

```
sudo e4defrag -c ~/
```

and if the score is bad (higher than 50, say), use the same command without the '-c' flag to defragment the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Most file systems do not compact directories after deletions. What worked for me is the answer to this [older question](https://askubuntu.com/a/385465/229197):

- Create a new folder
- Copy existing files and folders to the new folder
- Delete the slow folder
- Rename the new folder name to the old folder name